# How to create objects for inserting in DB using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, backend

Again I stuck with simple ruby app.
Before I created it using forms, but now I rewrited it using AJAX.
In body of AJAX I've got:

```
commenter:John Doe
body:Mint
```

in controller (it old part from part with forms)

```
 @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
```

How I could pass values from my request to comment_params (I mean comment and body to save it in db)?
 here perfomance of the comment:

```
  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you `comment_params`, you should have params like:

```
comment: {
  body: 'Test',
  commenter: 'TestUser'
}
```

Also, regarding your controller you should have nested route, like
`/articles/:id/comments`, so in your action you first initialize article:
`@article = Article.find(params[:id]` and then do the rest !

My advice is to try with `curl` or `Postman`, or even much better, try to write **request specs** so you can be sure comment is created as well. Then just create simply ajax request from form and that's it.

Cheers

Comment: I already made one fix on the front end : I send an object comment_params. and create it like this:  @comment = @article.comments.create(params[:comment_params]). Its inserted - but with values which is empty in view afterwards. May be you know how to fix it.

Comment: `comment = Comment.new(comment_params)` and then check if `comment.valid?` returns `true` or `false`. If it is `false` then check the error by running `comment.errors.message` and fix them. After that just create like you're doing now.

Comment: @FridmanChan why do you use `params[:comment_params]`? It should be `@article.comments.create(comment_params)`. Also, can you just debug and post here what is inside `params` or `comment_params` so I can give you more details ?